# Save arp output in terminal to text file every minute using crontab

Tags: cron

Goal: Have crontab running at start up logging output from `arp` command in a txt file.

```
> Chrontab:
> 
> # daemon's notion of time and timezones.
> #
> # Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
> # email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
> #
> # For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
> # at 5 a.m every week with:
> # 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
> #
> # For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
> #
> # m h  dom mon dow   command

* * * * * arp -n > results.txt
```

Unfortunately, instead of writing the output of `arp -n` it overwrites results.txt with a blank file.

The weird thing is if I use `arp-n > results.txt` in the terminal I get:

```
GNU nano 2.2.6               File: results.txt                                                      

Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask                Iface
192.168.42.19                    (incomplete)                          wlan0
192.168.42.14            ether   (incomplete)        C                 wlan0
192.168.42.13                    (incomplete)                          wlan0
192.168.42.18                    (incomplete)                          wlan0
192.168.1.1              ether   (incomplete)        C                  eth0
192.168.1.25             ether   (incomplete)        C                  eth0
192.168.42.12            ether   (incomplete)        C                 wlan0
192.168.1.240            ether   (incomplete)        C                  eth0
192.168.42.11                    (incomplete)                          wlan0
192.168.42.16                         M A                              wlan0
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can get it running and updating the file using crontab?

Comment: Have you considered installing `arpwatch` instead?

Comment: @roaima yeah, have been writing an answer around that too. It doesnt make much sense reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that probably crontab does not know the PATH where the arp command lives.

I would use:

```
* * * * * /usr/sbin/arp -n >> results.txt
```

However, I would use arpwatch to monitor ARP changes. It work as a daemon, and as it registers the MAC changes in a file over time, together with the epoch time of the change. It also is able to send messages to syslog and emails.

From [man arpwatch](https://linux.die.net/man/8/arpwatch)

> Arpwatch keeps track for ethernet/ip address pairings. It syslogs
>   activity and reports certain changes via email. Arpwatch uses pcap(3)
>   to listen for arp packets on a local ethernet interface.
>
> *Report Messages*
>
> Here's a quick list of the report messages generated by arpwatch(1)
>   (and arpsnmp(1)):
>
> new activity This ethernet/ip address pair has been used for the first
>   time six months or more.
>
> new station The ethernet address has not been seen before.
>
> flip flop The ethernet address has changed from the most recently seen
>   address to the second most recently seen address. (If either the old
>   or new ethernet address is a DECnet address and it is less than 24
>   hours, the email version of the report is suppressed.)
>
> changed ethernet address The host switched to a new ethernet address.
>
> *Syslog Messages*
>
> Here are some of the syslog messages; note that messages that are
>   reported are also sysloged.
>
> ethernet broadcast The mac ethernet address of the host is a broadcast
>   address.
>
> ip broadcast The ip address of the host is a broadcast address.
>
> bogon The source ip address is not local to the local subnet.
>
> ethernet broadcast The source mac or arp ethernet address was all ones
>   or all zeros.
>
> ethernet mismatch The source mac ethernet address didn't match the
>   address inside the arp packet.
>
> reused old ethernet address The ethernet address has changed from the
>   most recently seen address to the third (or greater) least recently
>   seen address. (This is similar to a flip flop.)
>
> suppressed DECnet flip flop A "flip flop" report was suppressed
>   because one of the two addresses was a DECnet address.
>
> *Files*
>
> /var/lib/arpwatch - default directory
>
> arp.dat - ethernet/ip address database
>
> ethercodes.dat - vendor ethernet block list

Comment: Anedoctal tale...once a supplier spoofed one of our IP addressed and we were running arpwatch in that network...

Comment: why were they doing that?  laziness, stupidity, or malice?

Comment: @cas Never attribute to malice that which is adequatly explained by stupidity. ;)

Comment: Wow, that worked great! Thank you for your detailed response. I didn't consider that crontab+ couldn't find the PATH for the arp command.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the `>` to a `>>`.  Using just one `>` will truncate the file before writing to it, using two will append.  You might also want to do something to make sure the file itself doesn't get too big.

Comment: He said he got a 'blank' file. Not one with one set of output in it. So I'm wondering if it's something else.

Comment: @Bob probably [couldn't find `arp` in the `$PATH`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/380008/100397) so ended up just truncating the file.

Comment: Good point. I should have added that.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't notice the 'blank' part...

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions about `arpwatch` are good ones, but if you don't want to go down that road:

I would suggest creating a file containing:

```
#!/bin/sh
arp -n >> results.txt
```

(note the `>>` or you'll get an error after the first run). Make sure it's executable with:

```
chmod 755 file
```

and then run that from the crontab.

Comment: Other than the `>>` instead of `>` how would this solve the problem?